# Problem with building apk on android with buildozer

Tags: python, android, linux, kivy, buildozer

Im new in kivy and Im trying to build helloworld in python/kivy on linux and for some reason I get this error and idk what to do with it

here is buildozer.spec `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kUigxxOkf-HBF4qXwtcmfrVLZtJTkHtK/view?usp=sharing`

here is full output from console `https://drive.google.com/file/d/19YCXJ73oEHnl78-R2DoKlFuECkLfO6OW/view?usp=sharing`

(for some reason stackowerflow says it looks like a spam when i put there just error so i must upload it on googledrive)

I hope somebody can help me with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ValueError: storage dir path cannot contain spaces, please specify a path with --storage-dir

This is the error it's printed for you. It seems fairly clear. Try building in a folder without a space in the name.